# Como guardar archivo XML en base de datos PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, xml, plsql

Necesito almacenar el texto de un archivo **XML** que ya tengo almacenado en una ubicación de un FTP, en un campo de una tabla en la base de datos, estoy haciendo uso del paquete `UTL_FILE` para leer archivos, no tengo muy claro el funcionamiento del paquete y apenas comienzo con el tema de los procedimientos en **PL/SQL**. Mi enfoque hasta el momento es:

1. Usar `UTL_FILE.FOPEN` para abrir el archivo.
2. Crear un `INSERT` dentro del procedimiento para almacenar en un campo de la base de datos

Para esto estoy realizando un procedimiento en **PL/SQL** no se si sea lo correcto para lo que estoy requiriendo

```
 DECLARE

    l_bfile BFILE;
    l_clob CLOB;
    VFILE UTL_FILE.file_type;
    TEXT VARCHAR2(32767);
    L_CONN UTL_TCP.connection;
    P_CMTT_CODE S.CMTT_CODE%TYPE;
    P_TEXT      S.TEXT%TYPE;
    P_TEXT_NAR  S.TEXT_NAR%TYPE;

BEGIN

    L_CONN := FTP.LOGIN('000.00.000.00', '00', '*********', '*********');
    FTP.ASCII(P_CONN => L_CONN);
    FTP.GET(P_CONN => L_CONN, p_from_file => '/xml_file/ES0000251446.xml', p_to_dir => 'UPLOAD_DIR',  p_to_file => 'ES0000251446.xml');
    ftp.logout(l_conn);

    VFILE := UTL_FILE.fopen('UPLOAD_DIR', 'ES0000251446.xml', 'R', 4000);

    LOOP
        BEGIN
            UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(VFILE, TEXT, 32767);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TEXT);
            INSERT INTO TABLE (
                     ID,
                     CMTT_CODE,
                     TEXT,
                     TEXT_NAR,
                     ACTIVITY_DATE)
                            VALUES('15218',
                                   '15',
                                   P_TEXT,
                                   P_TEXT_NAR,
                                   SYSDATE)
                                   RETURN TEXT_NAR INTO l_clob;

         l_bfile := BFILENAME ('UPLOAD_DIR', 'ES0000251446027471.xml');
         dbms_lob.fileopen( l_bfile, dbms_lob.FILE_READONLY );
         dbms_lob.loadfromfile( l_clob, l_bfile, dbms_lob.getlength(l_bfile) );
         dbms_lob.fileclose( l_bfile );
         COMMIT;

         EXCEPTION 
            WHEN OTHERS THEN EXIT;
                   dbms_output.put_line('Error al cargar el archivo');  

        END;
    END LOOP;

    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(VFILE);

END;
```

Donde `P_CMTT_CODE` va guardar por defecto el valor 15, `P_TEXT` guarda el nombre del archivo **XML** y `P_TEXT_NAR` todo el contenido, quiero decir todo el texto del **XML** en la tabla `TABLE`.

Aun no logro hacer la inserción de todo el texto XML en el campo `P_TEXT_NAR` de la tabla `TABLE`.

Estoy tratando de cumplir con mi filosofía de mantenerlo simple, pero soy nuevo en todo esto y realmente agradecería algunos comentarios sobre la mejor manera de hacerlo.

El error principal es que no me guarda el nombre del **XML** y ni lo que contiene el archivo **XML** en sus correspondientes campos

**Actualizacion:**

Intente hacerlo con la función `BFILENAME` pero al momento de insertarlos lo guarda de la siguiente manera, adicional a esto no guarda aun el nombre del archivo **XML**:

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas usar el paquete `DBMS_LOB`.

A final de cuentas los LOBs son apuntadores al contenido del archivo.
Primero tienes que crear el CLOB con `empty_clob()` desde el `INSERT` y recuperamos el apuntador por medio de la cláusula `RETURN`; después copias el contenido a partir de un BFILE, que es simplemente un LOB alojado en el sistema de archivos del servidor.

```
DECLARE

    l_bfile BFILE;
    l_clob CLOB;
    L_CONN UTL_TCP.connection;
    P_CMTT_CODE SPRCMNT.SPRCMNT_CMTT_CODE%TYPE;
    P_TEXT      SPRCMNT.SPRCMNT_TEXT%TYPE;
    P_TEXT_NAR  SPRCMNT.SPRCMNT_TEXT_NAR%TYPE;

BEGIN

    L_CONN := FTP.LOGIN('000.00.000.00', '00', '*********', '*********');
    FTP.ASCII(P_CONN => L_CONN);
    FTP.GET(P_CONN => L_CONN, p_from_file => '/xml_file/ES0000251446027471.xml', p_to_dir => 'UPLOAD_DIR',  p_to_file => 'ES0000251446027471.xml');
    ftp.logout(l_conn);

    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO SPRCMNT ( SPRCMNT_CMTT_CODE
                            , SPRCMNT_TEXT
                            , SPRCMNT_TEXT_NAR
                            )
            VALUES( P_CMTT_CODE
                  , P_TEXT
                  , empty_clob()
                  )
            RETURN SPRCMNT_TEXT_NAR INTO l_clob; 

        l_bfile := bfilename('UPLOAD_DIR', 'ES0000251446027471.xml');
        dbms_lob.fileopen( l_bfile, dbms_lob.FILE_READONLY );
        dbms_lob.loadfromfile( l_clob, l_bfile, dbms_lob.getlength(l_bfile) );
        dbms_lob.fileclose( l_bfile );

        COMMIT;
    EXCEPTION 
        WHEN OTHERS THEN    
            dbms_output.put_line('Error al cargar el archivo');
    END;

END;
```

Comment: Intente realizar lo de tu posible respuesta pero el **XML** no me lo guarda de la forma correcta, adicional a esto hace falta guardar el nombre del archivo **XML**, revisa la ultima actualización de mi pregunta

Comment: El nombre del archivo lo conoces de antemano, sólo deberías mandarlo en el insert. Si lo recibes como parámetro asegúrate que se envía en la invocación.

Comment: Si conozco el nombre del archivo, pero este procedimiento me toca hacerlo con varios archivos **XML**

Comment: Después de la asignación de `l_bfile` debugea `dbms_lob.substr(l_bfile,100)`.

Comment: El nombre del archivo lo tienes en código duro y supongo que no va a quedar así; cuando y donde modifiques eso podrás arreglar nombre para el `INSERT`. No puedo decirte mas por que desconozco cómo estás invocando el código.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105146/discussion-between-sebastian-salazar-and-sal).

Answer (score -1):

Necesitas hacerlo utilizando un **OPENROWSET BULK**, es bastante sencillo si estás trabajando con rutas específicas.

Digamos que tú tienes este **XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Customers>
  <Customer>
    <Document>000 000 000</Document>
    <Name>Clark Kent</Name>
    <Address>Metropolis, 1212</Address>
    <Profession>Loquito</Profession>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <Document>000 000 001</Document>
    <Name>Barry Allen</Name>
    <Address>Central City, 1212</Address>
    <Profession>Velocista</Profession>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <Document>000 000 002</Document>
    <Name>Bruce Wayne</Name>
    <Address>Gotham City, 1212</Address>
    <Profession>Vigilante</Profession>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

Ejecutas el siguiente Query:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS_TABLE (DOCUMENT, NAME, ADDRESS, PROFESSION)
SELECT
   MY_XML.Customer.query('Document').value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)'),
   MY_XML.Customer.query('Name').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   MY_XML.Customer.query('Address').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   MY_XML.Customer.query('Profession').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)')
FROM (SELECT CAST(MY_XML AS xml)
      FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\temp\MSSQLTIPS_XML.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)) AS T(MY_XML)
      CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('Customers/Customer') AS MY_XML (Customer);
```

y daría como resultado lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @AnibalRetro muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero en mi caso necesito hacerlo con todo el texto que incluya el XML y este almacenarlo en un campo de tipo CLOB, es un XML bastante extenso y hacerlo linea por linea seria un largo trabajo

Comment: conoces alguna forma de hacerlo con todo el texto que contiene el XML

Comment: Por favor evita realizar varías respuestas, edita tu respuesta para mejorarla,revisar [answer], saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes ingresar el XML desde alguna ubicación en tu PC, solo necesitas configurar tu Tabla de manera correcta para que se adapte al XML & no tengas perdida de datos, en tu caso si es muy extenso el XML puedes hacer esto.

Aclaro que este no es mi query, sin embargo puede servirte.

```js
CREATE DATABASE OPENXMLTesting
GO

USE OPENXMLTesting
GO

CREATE TABLE XMLwithOpenXML
(
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
XMLData XML,
LoadedDateTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\OpenXMLTesting.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

SELECT * FROM XMLwithOpenXML
```

Comment: La sentencia que colocas como respuesta es para MySQL o ORACLE? aun no lo he podido probarlo, pero quiero preguntar si este almacena el archivo XML como tal o todo el contenido del XML, en fin lo que necesito luego es generar un reporte e imprimir todo lo que contiene el XML

Comment: Ya comprobé que la función `OPENROWSET` es de SQLServer no de ORACLE, mi procedimiento lo estoy realizando el Oracle, ¿Qué guía o tutorial estás siguiendo que indica que es válido para usar en Oracle?

Comment: Por favor evita realizar varías respuestas, edita tu respuesta para mejorarla,revisar [answer], saludos.